# ¿No se puede cambiar un caracter con .charAt()?

Tags: java

Quiero hacer un programa java para reemplazar espacios con `% 20`. Pensaba hacer una bucle y cuando encuentre un `" "` reemplazo el caracter  con los tres caracteres. Sin embargo tengo un problema con `.charAt()`. En efecto parece que no se puede cambiar un caracter. Aqui esta el error :

```
replaceSpaces.java:8: error: unexpected type
                s.charAt(i)="%20";
                        ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

Aquí está el programa entero :

```
public class replaceSpaces{
    String s = "Hello Antoine";
    public static void replaceSpaces(String s){
        for(int i = 0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)==' '){
                s.charAt(i)="%20";
            }
        }
    System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`string.charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) retorna una nueva instancia del caracter que este en la posicion indicada por lo que no puedes editar ese caracter en el string.

Intenta utilizando el metodo `string.replace()` para reemplazar todos los carateres igual al primer parametro:

```
public static void replaceSpaces(String s){
       s = s.replace(" ", "%20");
       System.out.println(s);
}
replaceSpaces("Hello Antoine"); // imprime Hello%20Antoine
```

Ten en encuenta que `String` es inmutable por lo que siempre retornara una nueva instancia, así que tendras que retornar el resultado en vez de asignarlo a la variable `s` si quieres obtener el string con los espacios reemplazados:

```
 public static string replaceSpaces(String s){
     return s.replace(" ", "%20");
 }
 String texto = replaceSpaces("Hello Antonie");
 System.out.println(texto);// Hello%20Antonie
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberias de hacerlo con el metodo del objecto String:

> replaceAll("a", "b")

En este caso remplaza las coincidencias de "a" por "b".

En tu caso seria:

```
public static void replaceSpaces(String s){
    String s = "Hello Antoine";
    String res = ""; 
    res = s.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); // remplaza espacios por %20
    System.out.println(res); // "Hello%20Antoine"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El método que buscas es `replace`, que busca en una cadena la letra y la reemplaza por otra. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
String s = "Hello Antoine";
System.out.println(s);
//Primer parámetro letra a buscar y segundo parámetro letra a reemplazar
String replace = s.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
System.out.println(replace);
```

Salida:

```
Hello Antoine
Hello%20Antoine
```

Para mas información la documentación oficial aquí:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)